# c# custom class perform type checking inside of properties method

Tags: c#

Is there a better way to perform type checking inside of properties for custom classes?

For instance:

```
namespace DataTransferObjects
{
    public class sampleDTO
    {
        private string _fname;
        private string _lname;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get;
            set {_fname = value == null ? String.Empty : value.ToString(); }
        } 

        public string LastName
        {
            get;
            set { _lname = value == null ? String.Empty : value.ToString(); }
        }

    } // class
} // namespace
.
.
.
sampleDTO sDTO = new sampleDTO();
sDTO.FirstName = DataGridViewSample.Rows[0].Cells["FirstName"].Value;
sDTO.LastName = DataGridViewSample.Rows[0].Cells["LastName"].Value;
```

The problem is that the compiler will not allow an object to be passed into the class.

I could rewrite this as follows:

```
namespace DataTransferObjects
{
    public class sampleDTO
    {
        private string _fname;
        private string _lname;

        public object FirstName
        {
            get { return (object)_fname; }
            set {_fname = value == null ? String.Empty : value.ToString(); }
        } 

        public object LastName
        {
            get { return (object)_lname; }
            set { _lname = value == null ? String.Empty : value.ToString(); }
        }

    } // class
} // namespace
```

But this seems too clunky, since I now have to cast any calls as follows

```
string tempFirstName = sDTO.FirstName.ToString();
```

Any words of wisdom from the community?

Answer (score 2):

The correct thing to do is to use something like your first example, but cast the value to a `string` before you set the property:

```
sDTO.FirstName = DataGridViewSample.Rows[0].Cells["FirstName"].Value as string;
```

Your example does need to be fixed a little, though:

```
    public string FirstName
    {
        get {return _fname;}
        set {_fname = value ?? String.Empty; }
    }
```

Comment: sDTO.FirstName = (string)DataGridViewSample.Rows[0].Cells["FirstName"].Value; generates a runtime error if the value is null.

Comment: @RayLillback: No, it doesn't. `(string)null` works just fine.

Comment: @RayLillback: Ah, but if you mean that it's `DbNull`, then that makes sense. How about `sDTO.FirstName = DataGridViewSample.Rows[0].Cells["FirstName"].Value as string;`?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to perform type checking inside of properties for custom classes?

Do you mean *null checking*?  Because that's what the code in the property is doing.  You could shorten each setter to something like:

```
_fname = value ?? string.Empty;
```

The [null coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) essentially does what your conditional operator is doing in this case.  Return the first value if it is not null, or the second value if it is.  And you don't need `.ToString()` because the value is already a string.

But the "type checking" is already done by default, only a string can be passed to that property.

> The problem is that the compiler will not allow an object to be passed into the class.

Well, no.  C# is statically typed.  So you'd have to pass a string.  Which could be as simple as this:

```
sDTO.FirstName = DataGridViewSample.Rows[0].Cells["FirstName"].Value.ToString();
```

or perhaps:

```
sDTO.FirstName = (string)DataGridViewSample.Rows[0].Cells["FirstName"].Value;
```

> I could rewrite this as follows: [...]

You definitely don't want to make the properties be of type `object`, because then any time you *read* the property you'd have to cast/convert/etc.  The model itself would no longer be encapsulating what it actually represents and it would be up to *all* consuming code to do the work for it.

What you *can* do is maybe add other properties/methods for this purpose?  Consider a method such as:

```
public void SetFirstNameFromObject(object firstName)
{
    this.FirstName = firstName.ToString();
}
```

Or if you want to put it in a property:

```
public object FirstNameAsObject
{
    get { return this.FirstName; }
    set { this.FirstName = value.ToString(); }
}
```

(Including relevant error checking appropriately of course, left out of this example for brevity.)

Essentially you'd separate the *conversion* of the types from the actual model properties, creating a kind of pass-through operation which serves only to convert types.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear enough.  If I do this:

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear enough.  If I do this: stringTempStr = DGV.Rows[0].Cells["Name"].ToString() OR if I do this: string TempStr = (string)DGV.Rows[0].Cells["Name"].Value; and .Value is empty, then I get an error.

Comment: @RayLillback: Are you just looking for the `DBNull` object?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx  You can compare `.Value` against that to see if it represents a `null` value from the database.  It's kind of like an ADO.NET-specific version of checking for `null`.  So `== DBNull.Value` would be used just like any `== null`.

Comment: Darn, I was trying to abstract the workings of moving data values from a data grid view into a DTO.  My hope was to make this seamless to the UI logic (why would my UI care about the specifics on the storage)?  So, the easiest thing to do is a statement like this:  string TempStr = DGV.Rows[0].Cells["Name"].Value == null : ? String.Empty : DGV.Rows[0].Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();  Basically, we have to test the null condition before we call the .ToString() method.

Comment: I appreciate the assist!!

Comment: @RayLillback: Well, you have to test for `null` before you de-reference a reference variable.  Where you do that is up to you.  Any code can be encapsulated in a method or object somewhere.  So you can have a method which accepts an `object`, checks it for `null`, calls `.ToString()`, and returns the `string` (or a default if `null`).